# subtract value and update multiple rows

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a cart and I want to update database with the right stock values.
I get ordered products inserted into the table, but I can't update the stoc table with the right values.

```
foreach($_POST['produsC'] as $row=>$produsC) {

    $produsC=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$produsC);
    $masuraC=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,($_POST['masuraC'][$row]));
    $codutC=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,($_POST['codutC'][$row]));
    $cantitateC=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,($_POST['cantitateC'][$row]));
    $pretC=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,($_POST['pretC'][$row]));
    $tokC=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,($_POST['tokC'][$row]));
    $row_data[] = "('$tokC' , '$codutC' , '$produsC' , '$masuraC' , '$cantitateC' , '$pretC' , NOW())";
}

if (!empty($row_data)) {
$sql = 'INSERT INTO orders (order_id, idd, produs, masura, cantitate, pret, data) VALUES '.implode

(',', $row_data);
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
}

$up = "UPDATE stoc SET 
                    stoc = stoc - ".$cantitateC."
                WHERE prodid = '".$_POST['codutC'][$row]."' AND masura = '".$_POST['masuraC'][$row]."'";
                mysqli_query($link, $up);
```

Thx in advance

Comment: because you are using `$row` in last query and that is not coming.Reason is your foreach ended before this query and `$row` is gone.Also if any how you can retrieve that (which is possible), you will get the last record index.

Comment: and the solution would looklike....?!?

Comment: you want to update all rows or one row? also it you who can tell only why you use `$row` in `UPDATE` query.

Comment: @anant, I want to update all rows from stoc where codutC and masuraC.
I used $row, because I didnt know what to use :))
If I have 10 products, with different codutC and masuraC, I want to upload all in the stoc table.

I also tried to insert $up into the if(!empty($row_data) ... but still no effect